# Basic Authentication for IMAP/POP3 - GMAIL

Tags: gmail-api, gmail-imap

Google announced on March 30, 2020 that they were suspending turning off the less secure apps access until further notice. Can you please confirm that basic authentication with IMAP/POP3 will still work?. In other words, less secure apps with basic authentication with IMAP/POP3 will still work after June 15,2020.

Comment: Why do you ask a random group of developers and not the support of Google?

Comment: If Google announced something you can count on it being implemented.

Comment: @NicoHaase: I was on call with Google Support but we couldnt get a confirmation, so I asked it here

Answer (score 0):

As the [original plan](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/12/less-secure-apps-oauth-google-username-password-incorrect.html) stated, the disabling of Less-Secure Apps will deprecate basic authentication with IMAP and POP3.

Since this has been [delayed until further notice](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/03/less-secure-app-turn-off-suspended.html), no changes will be made yet.

**However**, I strongly suggest you update your application code to use OAuth. Less-Secure Apps are being deprecated for a very good reason, and you should take the extra time to migrate sooner rather than later.